# Do the abbreviations O, N, F mean anything on the electric meter terminals?

Tags: electrical

I am trying to troubleshoot a dual-energy heating installation.  I found [this diagram](http://www.hydroquebec.com/data/residentiel/pdf/schema-raccordement-bi-energie-en.pdf) from the electrical company.  The terminals below the meter face are labeled O, N, F, 12, and VCA.  12 I think is 12 volts, VCA is alternating current.  These are in French so I'm guessing O, N and F are as well.  If it helps: two of these terminals should act like a thermostat and close the circuit at a certain temperature (not sure which two,that's what I'm trying to troubleshoot).  I'm not sure what the third one does.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Quebec; the English language diagrams often don't translate the abbreviations

Answer (score 5):

The answer awoke me at 4am: It's a three way switch.  N = Neutre (neutral).  O = Ouvert (Open, this circuit is open in the diagram), F = Fermé (Closed, this circuit is closed in the diagram).